# Messages with Adium or third party client

Tags: messages

Is it possible to use Messages (Apple iMessage) with Adium or any other third party client.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the list of supported services on
https://adium.im/help/pgs/Accounts-ListOfServices.html
it looks like the answer would be no.